# Unable to load the voltage class java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/voltage/securedata/enterprise/VeException

Tags: java

I am trying to encrypt / decrypt messages using libvibesimplejava.so of 6.21 version where I have added the dependencies to load the jar from system path when I deployed to dev instance it's throwing this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/voltage/securedata/enterprise/VeException
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.voltage.securedata.enterprise.VeException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
```

Below is the code for library instantiation

```
Loading Library -
static {
        System.load("src/main/resources/****/libvibesimplejava.so");
    }
Library context instanitiation -
LibraryContext library = new LibraryContext.Builder()
                .setPolicyURL(policyURL)
                .setFileCachePath(cachePath)
                .setTrustStorePath(trustStorePath)
                .setClientIdProduct("****",
                        "***")
                .build();

Pom file -
 <dependency>
            <groupId>vibesimplejava</groupId>
            <artifactId>vibesimplejava</artifactId>
            <version>6.21.0.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${basedir}/src/main/resources/****/lib/vibesimplejava.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
```

Why it is failing to load the class in dev? Could any one suggest me the way to resolve this issue?

Comment: A source directory is not a good place for jar files. And it’s not unusual that this source directory does not exist in the deployed software.

Comment: @Holger ,thank you for the response.then whic path  can i give?